# Why do the items of a radio button list locate under it?

Tags: asp.net

I have a radio button list, but it's items is just under it. It's my code:

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
     <asp:ListItem>a</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>b</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

[image]

I don't want to locate the "a" and "b" under their circle,i want to locate besides them. How can I do it?

Comment: Might be an issue with your css files. Can you add them to the question?